# Error in my JSP page: The import java.util.List cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="**java.util.List**, br.com.alura.gerenciador.servlet.Empresa"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
```

Im having the red underline at line 3, in which im trying to impor "java.util.List

The error says: The import java.util.List cannot be resolved

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps the project is not set up correctly, does it show a "JRE System Library" inside the project in the Project Explorer (or Package Explorer)?

Comment: not sure about this "import="**java.util.List**, br.com.alura.gerenciador.servlet.Empresa" can you try <%@page import="java.util.List"%>